# Div position changing when typing content on it

Tags: html, css, css-float

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k5qHy/1/)

I have a line of divs and theorically I have no need to place inside an additional container div to keep them on the same line, as each of one has 15% width so can be placed on the same line.

They are correcly placed till you type anything on, then they go to a downer position for some reason I don't understand yet, and I am trying to solve without closing them on a container to avoid this. How can I?

Each one's CSS is:

```
.content-progra [class^="cono-"],
.content-progra [class*="cono-"]{
    width:15%; height:150px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:10px 0.5%;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Just add `vertical-align:top;` http://jsfiddle.net/k5qHy/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the vertical align on a display: inline-block element, you need to use `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to css class.this will work

Comment: Thank you, but I added a vertical top align in order to be able to center all content with a text-align center

Comment: @Biomehanika why don't accept any of our answer..that would help others

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `display: inline-block` to `float:left`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5qHy/4/)

Comment: Thank you, at least I added a vertical top align in order to be able to center all content with a text-align center